# php exec() not executing binary symlinked from /usr/bin/ to /usr/libexec/

Tags: php, apache, exec

I'm using PHP 5.5.6 and trying to use `exec()` to execute the `gitolite` binary that is located in `/usr/libexec/gitolite/gitolite` and is symlinked from `/usr/bin/gitolite` to that binary.

I am able to run other commands (such as `id`) that are located in `/usr/bin/`.  If I copy or hardlink the binary to `/usr/bin/gitolite`, it also works just fine.  But when it's symlinked to `/usr/libexec/gitolite` and I include `2>&1` at the end of the command string passed to `exec()`, the output is

> sh: find: command not found

It seems to me like there's a readlink going on somewhere and it sees that `/usr/libexec/gitolite` is not in some allowed list of directories, but the `safe_mode_exec_dir` configuration directive doesn't exist in PHP 5.5.

For what it's worth, this is running in Apache 2.4.6.

Comment: What user is apache running as? Try su-ing to that user and running the command from the terminal. Probably a problem with that user's PATH variable.

Comment: It's not a problem with the PATH because 1) I can even use the full path to the binary in the call to exec and it fails with the same problem, and 2) the php process is running as the 'git' user and I can confirm that /usr/bin/ is in that user's PATH.